# How to produce a progress bar with nodes in Android Studio?

Tags: android

[image: progress bar with nodes]

I am trying to produce something like this in Android Studio. I'm pretty sure I'm going to have to make a custom view, but I'm unsure of what class to extend. It looks like a progress bar, but none of the progress bar examples I've seen look like that. Is anyone familiar with how to implement this? I'm not asking for code, more just a push in the right direction (although if someone already has source code for it on hand it would be great to take a look at). Thank you!

Comment: This with an animation - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6931

Comment: @cricket_007 so that's what it's called! Fitting name. Thanks for the response. I've always been hesitant to use third-party libraries. Do you think it would be safe to use this one?

Comment: There's other libraries on that site, so if it doesn't work, find another